# Do we really need a [kinect-hacking] tag?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

When reviewing some suggested edits, I stumbled upon suggested content for the [kinect-hacking](/questions/tagged/kinect-hacking) tag-wiki. There are as of now 48 questions that have this tag. However, I would say there is no point in having it.

Those questions with the tag are equally well served by a [kinect](/questions/tagged/kinect) tag or a [openni](/questions/tagged/openni) tag. The fact that you might be doing something out of the ordinary with a Kinect (related to programming of course..sheesh) should be part of your question. And I don't think this deserves a special tag.

In summary: Do we need the [kinect-hacking](/questions/tagged/kinect-hacking) tag? Should we remove (and perhaps burninate) it?

**Update**: As of this time, all the 48 tags were removed and replaced with appropriate tags where necessary in addition to other fixes needed.

Comment: synonym of the `[1337-h4z0r]` master tag

Comment: You know you're getting old when the establishment starts to use leetspeak....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.  Edit it out and replace it with the appropriate [kinect](/questions/tagged/kinect) or [openni](/questions/tagged/openni) tag.

I've added it to https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128315/the-great-stack-overflow-tag-question-cleanup-of-2012